# npm install with prefix

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to lay out a project structure with multiple local packages, I'd like them to share the same node_modules folders so that npm install is fast, and disk space usage is moderate. Each package when used standalone has a few hundred MB of dependencies.

```
node_modules
main
  - package.json
packages
  lib1
    - package.json
  lib2
    - package.json
```

As an example each package depends on react, gulp and webpack, which will be defined as dependencies in each `package.json`.

I'm trying to work out how to have an easy script to install each packages dependencies into node_modules, but I can't make it work.

```
cd main
echo "prefix = .." > .npmrc
npm install 
for each in packages
  cd package
  echo "cat prefix = .." > .npmrc
  npm install
```

However, I can't make it work.

`npm install --prefix ..` also doesn't work without a package name, but as I'm trying to make this install all packages after a clone, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually [specify local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) for your dependencies directly in the top-level package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "lib1": "./pacakges/lib1",
  ...
}
...
```

Then you can just do one `npm install` in the top-level directory, and it will install the dependencies, just as any other node module!

Comment: This seems to make a copy of lib1 though? e.g. node_modules/lib1/node_modules now exists...

Comment: @Chris you're right... I'm guessing that won't really solve what you're trying to do...

Comment: sadly not, I thought it was my solution earlier today, and then was a little gutted when it didn't work... my other issue is that even with node_modules in the parent correctly populated (so that my app works), the next `npm install` in a local package will install everything locally - if i could work around that, i'd be happy and would just maintain a package.json in the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

**@Chris**, although you want to make *package.json* for yourself to work but to make things fast deployment you can just zip your ***npm_module*** folder  and add to git repo and while deployment you can just **unzip** the folder and *run*

```
  npm rebuild
```

This will be much faster.
Hope this will help you.